# How do you find the newest value in a column?

Tags: sql

How do you find the newest value in a column?  Only 1 column changes values and it is not the main identifier.

```
(select    ( t_Order_Assignment.dte_assignment )
from t_order_assignment  WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join t_order_detail on t_Order_Assignment.order_detail_id = t_order_detail.Order_Detail_ID)as 'dte_assignment'
```

This is also set inside a much larger query so the order by clause will not work.  I have tried `@@identity, scope, top 1`, and Last(doesn't work).  I just need the newest value in that specific column listed above.

Thanks

Comment: By newest value, are you talking about a datetime field?  If so, are you really asking how you find the record with the greatest datetime value?

Comment: dte_assignment 2011-12-19 04:29:44.010  but it is saved as a string and by newest I want the most recent entry placed in.  the main id does not change.

Comment: Also: **what  database** and which version?? Looks like SQL Server - is it?? Just "SQL" doesn't help - that's just the structured query language that almost all database systems use - just "SQL" isn't an identifiable product or vendor .....

Comment: If it's a **DATE** - **WHY** is it stored as a string ?!?!???!?!

Comment: You're not being very clear here.... **DEFINE** what the "latest" or "newest" row is - from which **table**, and ordered by **what column**?? It might be helpful to have the table structures and sample data and more explanation what you're trying to achieve....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so are you saying this would not work??

```
(select   top 1 t_Order_Assignment.dte_assignment
from t_order_assignment  WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join t_order_detail on t_Order_Assignment.order_detail_id =     t_order_detail.Order_Detail_ID
order by CAST(t_Order_Assignment.dte_assignment AS DateTime) desc
)as 'dte_assignment'
```

-- just saw the comment about storing dates as a string... not a good move but maybe out of your hands, so there is a cast on the order by. this has no error handling so you may want to look at that...

Comment: no that doesnt work because it grabbed the newest date not the latest entry.  For instance i manually changed the date to roll back 2 days and it still grabs a date that was placed in the system 2 minutes before that.

Comment: maybe i have to throw this method out--- i did the rollback for testing purposes

Comment: ok i get that, well then you can order it by the ID column if you have an auto increment column such as an integer ID value. it has been suggested in your original post

Comment: @Daren: so **what is the LATEST** entry if not the one with the newest date??????

Comment: @marc_s agreed, probably the record with the latest ID in the table? need further info

Comment: eventually the date will be the newest date but for my testing purposes I need it to read the date that was newly entered.(not necessarily a recent date)Thanks

Comment: @Daren: how do you know (or how can a T-SQL query know) that an "older" date has been newly updated?? Do you have an **update timestamp** or something??? You need to be able to **ORDER BY (column)** one way or another .... T-SQL cannot just magically **know** that this old date is new, while the other old date is old .....

Comment: @all  so here is what is happeneing after looking at the query..  If i change the date manually to a reverted date backa few days, it does not change the date in the query.  it still picks up the date prior to the modified date.  This column field does not create a new record for each change but rather changes just that field in the row.

Comment: @Daren without a unique auto incremented id column or a timestamp value suggested by marc_s, this is just not workable. suggest an auto id column to find the "newest" record.

Comment: OK thanks anyways it was worth a try.  The reason it is not auto incrementable is because they do not want a ton of records for 1 order that basicaly show the same information except the date assigned.  was worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a max() function on the index or key field on the table t_order_assignment?